# How to test Django admin?

Tags: python, django, testing, admin

I'm trying to test usage of the admin site. Simple tests, if viewing, adding, changing and deleting stuff works. This is my code so far:

```
    class BaseAdminTestCase(TestCase):
    """
    Base admin site test case, create admin user and login.
    """

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.login()

    def create_user(self):
        username, password = 'admin', 'test'
        user = User.objects.get_or_create(
            username=username,
            email='admin@test.com',
            is_superuser=True
        )[0]
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        self.user = user
        return username, password

    def login(self):
        username, password = self.create_user()
        self.client.login(username=username, password=password)


class ClientAdminTestCsae(BaseAdminTestCase):

    def test_get_client_list(self):
        page = '/logistirio/client/'
        resp = self.client.get(page, follow=True)
        assert resp.status_code == 200

    def test_create_client(self):
        resp = self.client.post(
            reverse('admin:logistirio_client_add'),
            {
                'title': "mr",
                'name': "Toni",
                'surname': "Montana",
                'phone1': "6969696969",
                'email1': "ant@gmail.com",
            },
        )
        print(resp)
        firstClient = client.objects.filter(pk=1).exists()
        self.assertTrue(firstClient)
```

The first test works, the second one doesn't, and I'm not sure why. The client object has inlines, if this is a problem. Has anyone any experience with this? Thank you.

Comment: What is the response?

Comment: It's quite large. Maybe an error, but I can't understand from the command line.